# How to merge array with json url

Tags: android, arrays, json

Array

private String[] title = {"dish","cuisine"};

json url

jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                    .getJSONfromURL("https://api.edamam.com/search?app_id=(id)&app_key=(key)&from=0&to=100");

How to merge that string array with json url to create a full link.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to concatenate (combine) the url strings with certain string objects from the array, you could simply access that string object by calling it's index.

```
String index_zero = title[0];
```

The variable index_zero would hold the value "dish" in this case. From this you could go:

```
String url = "beginning of url" + index_zero + " end of url";
```

Once the full url is constructed, you could do the api-call using the url variable:

```
...getJSONfromURL(url);
```

Comment: yes but the string array has multiple array values and i want to add that to end of json url. like jsonurl + array.

Comment: Yes, thats still possible. Just use jsonurl + title[0] + title[1]. However, remember to add any possible separators between the string objects gathered from the array, like underscores.

Comment: like this
getJSONfromURL(url+title[]);

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. If you want to provide the content of the array to the api you have to provide each object in the array as a parameter in the request since you're using a GET request or change the api to interpret a string provided as an array. However, if this is what you want to accomplish, I would suggest a POST request instead. This type of request has a body where you could put additional data, preferably in a json format.

Answer (score 1):

```
String url = "https://api.edamam.com/search?app_id="+ title[0] +"&app_key="+ title[1] +"&from=0&to=100";
JSONfunctions .getJSONfromURL(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String.format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) and pass an array of `Object` to it. The url string should be modified to include printf style place holders for the query arguments; here `%s` is used to format the strings:

```
String[] title = {"dish", "cuisine"};
String url = String.format("https://api.edamam.com/search?app_id=%s&app_key=%s&from=0&to=100", (Object[])title);
```

You can also include all query string parameters like this:

```
Object[] param_values = {"dish", "cuisine", 0, 100};
String url = String.format("https://api.edamam.com/search?app_id=%s&app_key=%s&from=%d&to=%d", param_values);
```

Then pass `url` to `getJSONfromURL()`.

N.B. you should also ensure that the values are properly encoded: see [`URLEncoder.encode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Comment: Thanks a lot :) i will try this.